# Why my DEFAULT_DICT still change despite I use dict(DEFAULT_DICT) to init other dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to have a python dictionary that never change.

In the following code, I was hoping that DEFAULT_DICT would not be changed :

```py
DEFAULT_DICT = {
    'history':{
        'id':[]
    }
}

my_dict = dict(DEFAULT_DICT)
print("my_dict is {}".format(my_dict))
print("DEFAULT_DICT is {}".format(DEFAULT_DICT))

my_dict['history']['id'].append("toto")
print("my_dict is {}".format(my_dict))
print("DEFAULT_DICT is {}".format(DEFAULT_DICT))
```

Can someone can tell me why DEFAULT_DICT is changing according to my_dict ?

I was thinking that use

```py
my_dict = dict(DEFAULT_DICT)
```

will correction the problem but not.

Comment: Use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest you read and start following the naming conventions described in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that when you wrote `my_dict = dict(DEFAULT_DICT)` shallow copy of DEFAULT_DICT was created, but you need a deep copy of this object.

To solve your problem you can use `deepcopy` function from `copy` module:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

DEFAULT_DICT = {
    'history': {
        'id': []
    }
}

my_dict = deepcopy(DEFAULT_DICT)
print("my_dict is {}".format(my_dict))
print("DEFAULT_DICT is {}".format(DEFAULT_DICT))

my_dict['history']['id'].append("toto")
print("my_dict is {}".format(my_dict))
print("DEFAULT_DICT is {}".format(DEFAULT_DICT))
```

For more information about shallow and deep copy follow this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).